# Looping Radio Button Check in Visual C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to C#, trying to make a program that is essentially a survey with 30 questions that are answered by selecting one of five radio buttons (Strongly Disagree, Disagree...Strongly Agree, etc).

I have set up a small "block" of code that will check which radio button is checked for the question and assign a value to an array (see below).

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void buttonScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBoxScoreOutput.Text = " ";

        int[] score = new int[2]; // Declares the integer of score and sets it to a value of zero

        // Question 1

        if (radioButtonSD1.Checked == true) // If Strongly Disagree checked give score a value of 1
            score[0] = 1;
        else if (radioButtonD1.Checked == true) // If Disagree checked give score a value of 2
            score[0] = 2;
        else if (radioButtonNS1.Checked == true) // If Not Sure checked give score a value of 3
            score[0] = 3;
        else if (radioButtonA1.Checked == true) // If Agree checked give score a value of 4
            score[0] = 4;
        else if (radioButtonSA1.Checked == true) // If Strongly Agree is checked give score a value of 5
            score[0] = 5;

        // Question 2

        if (radioButtonSD2.Checked == true) // If Strongly Disagree checked give score a value of 1
            score[1] = 1;
        else if (radioButtonD2.Checked == true) // If Disagree checked give score a value of 2
            score[1] = 2;
        else if (radioButtonNS2.Checked == true) // If Not Sure checked give score a value of 3
            score[1] = 3;
        else if (radioButtonA2.Checked == true) // If Agree checked give score a value of 4
            score[1] = 4;
        else if (radioButtonSA2.Checked == true) // If Strongly Agree is checked give score a value of 5
            score[1] = 5;

        // Output values in array to text box

        this.textBoxScoreOutput.Text = "Array: ";

        foreach (int i in score)
        {
            this.textBoxScoreOutput.Text += "[" + i.ToString() + "] ";
        }

        int sum = score.Sum();
        this.textBoxScoreOutput.Text += "The Sum of the array is: " + sum.ToString();
    }


}
}
```

So this is checking the first two of the thirty questions and is working exactly how I need it to and thought it would.

I was wondering if I could loop just one of these "blocks" and have it check all thirty questions. I have searched and searched but can't find exactly what I am looking for (I also understand I may not be searching for the right thing either).

I am just trying to avoid having thirty of these "blocks" in my program. I feel like it would just be a mess with thirty of these. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Radio buttons are meant to be in groups; in other words, one question should have one radio button group and each radio button in that group has a value.  It seems to me like you should be inspecting the 30 *groups* of radio buttons (not 5 individual radio button elements for 30 questions).  It's hard to know for sure if that's what you're doing without seeing the code and application, but, just an idea to make this more simple.

Comment: You should specify what UI technology you are using. The following UI technologies are supported by Visual Studio and support the concept of radio buttons: ASP.NET Web Forms, Windows Forms, Silverlight, WPF, Windows Store applications.

Comment: What type of controls are the dark gray boxes ?

Comment: I have each set of five radio buttons in a panel and I am using Windows Forms.

Comment: If I inspect them as group, can I still assign a specific value to the selected radio button?

Answer (score 2):

Start with creating a UserControl which encapsulates the logic for a single question:

- Question Text
- Selected option

Once you have a single question working, you can drop any number of User Controls on to a form, configure the question text and then only have to loop through the set of user controls to get your answers. The answer would be best returned as an [enumeration](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum).

There are a number of ways to achieve this, such as code to generate the controls, or binding the selections back to a ViewModel class, but a user control is a great start.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it roughly:

```
var resultList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();


foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control is GroupBox)
    {
         GroupBox gb = (GroupBox)control;
         foreach (Control controll in gb.Controls)
         {
             if (controll is RadioButton)
             {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                rb = (RadioButton)controll;
                //rb will allow you to access all of the RadioButton's properties and act accordingly.    
                if (rb.Checked)
                {
                    int score;
                    if (rb.Name.Contains("ButtonSD"))
                        score = 1;
                    if (rb.Name.Contains("ButtonD"))
                        score = 2;
                    //So on...
                    resultList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(gb.Name, score));

                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Had a rough day so maybe someone can come up with something better, but if you don't feel like reorganizing the whole thing, this might work.

Comment: I think I have seen this before and I am not sure this is what I am looking for (although, I am not exactly sure what I am looking for either). Will this allow me to assign a value to the radio button that ultimately is stored in the array score? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: this is most likely your answer to the question, you should have a good look in the code. If you are new to develpoment, these are very basic problem scenario and are pretty easy to counter.

Comment: Okay. I have poured over this for the past hour and I get the general idea of what is going on here, and it makes sense. But let me just make sure I get. 

It is looking at each control in the form and if it's a GroupBox it then checks to see if it is a RadioButton. If is is a RadioButton then it is checking the RabdioButton properties to see which ones are checked if it's checked for the text "ButtonSD" ... etc. Then it adds the value to a string name score. Am I following this?

Comment: When I attempt to add this code to my program I get an error in the line 'foreach (Control control in Form.Controls)' The error I get is this: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". I truly apologize for my noobness.

Comment: Form should be the actually name of your form, or tabPanel. Whatever's holding these groupBoxes.

Comment: This solution is too reliant the name of control being correct, if you wanted to go with this solution you should find a better way of determining the value of the control, such as creating an inherited RadioButton and adding a new integer property to it, then use this control on the form. Also, adding all your group boxes, or radio buttons to a List up front would simplify this code enormously.

Comment: Sure is, but I tried to provide a solution that remotely deals with the situation at hand. Telling someone (a self admitted newbie) to scrap everything and start from scratch is useful when providing a more solid solution, but not enough IMO.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think that I jumped the gun a little bit as I don't a have good enough understanding of some fundamentals of Visual C# to fully understand all of this (I am literally in the middle of a book on Visual C#). I will read up some more and come back to this later on. I will be sure to update it when I do. Thanks again for all your help!